# Java - recursively modify object values with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to transform every String property of an Object (along with its nested objects) and I am using the following recursive method to achieve that with reflection API:

```
    public static void reflect(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return;
        }
        Class klazz = obj.getClass();
        if (klazz.isPrimitive()
                || obj instanceof Integer
                || obj instanceof Double
                || obj instanceof Boolean)
            return;
        else {
            try {
                for (Field field : klazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object f = field.get(obj);
                    if(f instanceof String) {
                        f = transform(f);
                        field.set(obj, f);
                    }
                    else {
                        reflect(f);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Object transform(Object f) {
        f = f + "blabla";
        return f;
    }


@Data
@Builder
public class PrintObject {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private NestedObject field4;
}

@Data
@Builder
public class NestedObject {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private Integer field3;
}

NestedObject nestedObject = NestedObject
                .builder()
                .field1("test")
                .field2("test2")
                .field3(1)
                .build();

PrintObject printObject = PrintObject
      .builder()
      .field1("test")
      .field2("Test")
      .field3("test")
      .field4(nestedObject)
      .build();

Utils.reflect(printObject);
```

Up to this point every works fine and if I execute this, then all String values are appended with "blabla" in the end.
Problem comes if PrintObject has other data structures like List, or Map.
For example if there is another field in PrintObject class:

```
private List<String> field5;
```

then this code execution would throw StackOverflowError.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("test");

NestedObject nestedObject = NestedObject
                .builder()
                .field1("test")
                .field2("test2")
                .field3(1)
                .build();

PrintObject printObject = PrintObject
      .builder()
      .field1("test")
      .field2("Test")
      .field3("test")
      .field4(nestedObject)
      .field5(list)
      .build();

Utils.reflect(printObject);
```

Any idea on how to make this work with these structures as well?
Thanks in advance.

field5 could also be for example:

```
 Map<String,String>
```

or even

```
 List<List<String>>
```

Comment: what do you want to do for `List` and `Map`? Do you want to transform `keys` inside `Map`?

Comment: Matt Champion already provided a good answer on where the loop comes from. As for the list and map handling — you'd have to add a special case for them and iterate through elements instead of going through the inner fields of these classes. Note that due to type erasure, you won't be able to determine the parameterized type of the list with reflection — you'd have to go through all elements one by one and check for their type. But you'll face some even more interesting challenges, like how to deal with immutable lists of strings, for example, which you won't be able to change at all.

Comment: I could add a method that goes through all elements of the List and modifies the values  if they are Strings. That would work. But what for example if we have a data structure like List<List<List<String>>> or a Map<String, List<String>> and I want to modify all string values of these data structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList` contains a `long` `serialVersionUID` field to help with serialisation. When you get the value it returns a boxed `Long`. Calling `getDeclaredFields` on `Long` returns an array containing the field `Long.MIN_VALUE` which is a `Long`. That's where the infinite loop comes from.

To resolve it I would add special case handling for `Long` like you do for `Integer`. You should also consider all the other boxed primitives like `Float` and `Byte`.

Collections will be backed either by structures that refer to each other link `LinkedList` or by arrays. For linked structures the code would traverse them. To support array backed collected you need to identify which fields are arrays and iterate over them.

The type of a field and be obtained with [Field.getType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType--). Arrays can be identified by [Class.isArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray--). Arrays for different types have different types, they are not non-reified like Java generics. Arrays of non-primitive values can be cast to `Object[]` that is useful in this case but it is [not type safe](http://www.pmg.csail.mit.edu/papers/popl97/node19.html). To get the type of object in the array [Class.getComponentType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType--) can be used.

Something like the following would be needed to recurse on the entries of an array.

```
final Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
if (fieldType.isArray() && !fieldType.getComponentType().isPrimitive()) {
    Object[] fs = (Object[]) f;
    for (Object fi : fs) {
        reflect(fi);
    }
}
```

The other problem is cyclic references that could cause further `StackOverflowException`. If a list was added as a member to itself it would recurse infinitely. It is necessary to track previously visited object and not visit them twice. Ideally this would use an `IdentityHashMap` as you care about instances of objects not their equality.

Comment: Right. The problem of not throwing StackOverflow Exception is solved in that way. But then I have to also transform the String values of the Map or the List somehow.